# PHP : how to insert (into an Sql table) a variable and concatenate it with the date function

Tags: php, sql

i've been trying to insert a row into an Sql database table , and that row's last column is supposed to contain a variable and i can't figure out how to concatenate that variable with a date function. The problem becomes the single quote marks

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$text'.'date('Y-m-d H:i:s')')";
```

That $text is supposed to have a "date now" function called right after it so that i would have the date that it was inserted into the table...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, '$user', '$text<br>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')";
```

Comment: Someone edited my answer to erroneously change the code, why people do that? I've edited it back.

Comment: No, that person proposed an edit. Then people approve. This is a far more complex social issue [...]. Just rollback

Comment: @user2227494 It's working perfectly fine in this demo http://codepad.org/MKk6juoM You probably have an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO news VALUES (NULL, '$user', '".$text." now()')";
```